# PowerBuilder Oracle "DBMS ORA is not supported" error on one dev machine but not the other

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, powerbuilder

We recently switched from Oracle 10g to 11g. When trying to run our app from PB, dev machine A works fine, but dev machine B gives "999 DBMS ORA is not supported ..." We are getting SQLCA.DBMS from a .ini file which is set to ORA (to work with 11g client). If we change this to O10 (to work with 10g client) then machine B works. The strange thing is that both A and B have the same path (pointing to the same 11g instant client on the network), so it's not related to that. We need to use the 11g client since we are planning to drop support for 10g. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three characters of SQLCA.DBMS correspond to characters 3-5 of the driver name. For example, the O10 driver for PB 12.5 would be PB**O10**125.DLL.

Make sure that machine B has the driver PB**ORA**###.DLL where ### is the PB version (you didn't say).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought it was a driver problem, but I was looking at the PBODB125.dll file instead of PBORA125.dll. Thanks again.